# Opposing Laser Beams Turns One Laser Off

Tags: visible-light, laser, light-emitting-diodes, laser-interaction

When I send two separate laser beams directly into each other one of the beams goes completely out. These are inexpensive 5mv red diode lasers. What’s happening inside the laser to make it “turn off”? When the beams are not opposing the “turned off” laser returns to its normal function. 
Note: The use of a a beam splitter allows me to see effects.
Update here are two videos I posted showing my experiment results.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n66R_OVeiGc
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsJ5sMncu_g

Comment: This is interesting, do you have any photographs or a video showing the effect?

Comment: Also can you be more clear what you mean by effects? And can you describe (perhaps with a diagram) your experimental setup in more detail?

Comment: @Philip For some reason my phone won’t allow me to up load a photo, not sure why. The two lasers are pointing directly at each other. A beam splitter is placed between them at 45degrees. When the beams are directed into each other one beam goes completely out.

Comment: @Mr.HelloBye As the beams are brought together dimming occurs and finally lights out. Also, I have done the experiment by sending an opposing beam "backwards through an interferometer where a phase shift is seen.

Comment: Generating lots of excess carriers could well short out one diode.

Comment: @JonCuster Would that be a temporary or permanent change? Sounds the most promising answer so far. I want to try this out. Lambda, do try to upload a photo or video or something, would love to see this!

Comment: Could be either depending on the device and the power supply (e.g. current limited).

Comment: The beam does not turn off instantly. Dimming occurs first if the beams are brought into alignment slowly.

Comment: @Philip I will post something to YouTube maybe this evening.

Comment: @Philip I added videos to the question.

Comment: This is pretty cool. I'm going to try this out myself and let you know if I see the same thing.

Comment: you should monitor the laser current from the power supply. if it drops this could tell you the light path is disrupted and the laser is not lasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe interference is the reason you don't see the beam from laser 2. I believe laser 1 is somehow turning off laser 2.

There are spots and side fringes on both cards that do not change when laser 2 is turned on or off. They are entirely from laser 1. Laser 1 is shining into laser 2, reflecting back out, bouncing off the beamsplitter and lighting up the left card. You can see this particularly at the end of the second video. So the dim spot on the left card is not output from laser 2.

Laser 2 always turns abruptly on or off. This happens when light from laser 1 is blocked, or even dimmed by smoke. If this was interference, you would expect laser 2 to fade out as smoke dimmed laser 1.

Plainly the situation is not symmetric. Laser 2 does not shut off laser 1. Perhaps laser 2 is not precisely aimed into laser 1. Perhaps laser 1 is brighter than laser 2. Perhaps it is something else.

---

I can speculate about a mechanism where one laser would turn another off, but I could easily be wrong.

A laser is an active medium in a cavity. An energy source keeps exciting atoms in the medium. The atoms emit light when they decay back to a lower energy state.

When an atom is excited, it will spontaneously decay if left alone. But if another photon of the right frequency hits it, it can be stimulated to decay and emit a photon. When this happens, the emitted photon has the same direction and phase as the first photon. This is what makes laser light coherent.

Without a cavity, an active medium is just a light. Not enough photons stimulate atoms before escaping.

The cavity is two mirrors facing each other so that light on the right path repeats the path over and over. One mirror is partially reflecting so that some light can get out of the cavity.

When a laser starts up, light is emitted in all directions. Much of it escapes. But some happens to be in just the right direction to reflect back and forth. This light stays in the medium and is much more likely to stimulate atoms to emit light. The stimulated light is also in just the right direction to stay in the cavity. This light is amplified, while other light is not. In a very short time, almost all the light in the cavity is traveling in the right direction. Some gets through the partially reflecting mirror, and this is the beam you see. This gives us the word laser: Light Amplification by the Stimulated Emission of Radiation.

Excited atoms emit a narrow range of wavelengths. Note that the wavelength of the light must match the cavity length just right. The round trip distance in the cavity must be an integer number of wavelengths for constructive interference. In a gas laser with a very long cavity, this isn't a problem. Suppose a frequency where 1,000,000,000 wavelengths makes a round trip isn't quite perfect. A slightly higher frequency where 1,000,000,001 wavelengths is a round trip might be better. There may be several possibilities within the range emitted by the medium.

Laser diodes have much shorter cavities. They may still have multiple possible wavelengths (or modes). But there will not be as many. Frequencies where 100 or 101 wavelengths fit are more widely separated.

If you shine a second laser into the cavity, it most likely will not be exactly lined up with the cavity mirrors. Two independent diode lasers will have different cavity lengths. They are not likely to match exactly the same frequencies. So it will not reflect back and forth many times. It might reflect a few times at best, but it will not contribute to a laser beam.

There are losses in a laser cavity. Some light is absorbed by the medium. Some through the mirror. Some is spontaneously emitted in the wrong direction. For a laser beam to form, amplification must exceed loss.

Light from a second laser is another source of loss. Excited atoms are stimulated to emit in the wrong direction. This might be enough to make loss exceed amplification, and stop the laser.

Comment: After additional testing I think your right.  Here are some results I have discovered: If one laser is removed and replace by a mirror I am unable the turn off the laser with its own light. Not sure why but seems to be the case. In the two laser configuration if I slowly decrease the beam of the “dominant” laser by rotating polarizing film the dominant beam fades as the other increases.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a comment:

Lasing is a quantum mechanical effect. This means that the quantum mechanical wave  functions have to take into account the boundary conditions of the whole set up.

[See this MIT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRi4dv9KgCg) where it shows that when there is in total blackout interference of two beams the photons go back to the laser that gave them substance.

I suspect *if your two lasers are of the same frequency* *hitting the atoms giving the stimulated emmision* the lasing crystal of one of  them gets total "black out " interference in stimulating an emission, depending on the distance between them and the phases.

Edit after comments:

In this link the question is raised [whether independent light beams interfere](https://www.researchgate.net/post/The_interference_between_two_different_lasers_at_the_same_wavelength), and a  lot of links are given that answer in the affirmative with experiments done from the beginning of laser research.  Also the effect is used [commercially](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/interfering-beam):

> Photonic structures such as gratings can be rapidly fabricated by laser interference lithography, where multiple laser beams are overlapped in a photosensitive material. The spatial intensity distribution of the interfering beams is translated into a physical structure of the photoresist.

So independent coherent beams do interfere. My comment above tried to look at it at the quantum mechanical level, where individual photons are taken into account as well as energy conservation.

It seems that the question did not catch the attention of experts in optics following this site.

Comment: Given the linewidth of a typical cheap laser diode, any destructive interference between two separate lasers would last less than a microsecond.

Comment: @ThePhoton I m not talking of interference of the two beams. If you watch the video    I gave a link for, you will see I am talking of the system, including the two lasing media.

Comment: In that case how does your answer relate to OP's question, which was about light from one laser entering a second laser's aperture and causing the second laser to turn off?

Comment: Since I posted I have more info: Not sure this happens with all lasers. The lasers I have used are focusable three wires (red, yellow and black)TTL 35khz lasers. I have them connected so they stay on. Red and yellow together to one side of the battery and black to the other. Sorry for this late info. Did consider it relevant until now.

Comment: Just tried it with a simple two wire laser diode and it still turns off when another laser is directed into it. So the question is what’s causing this to happen. It seems that only a laser of the same or close to the same frequency works. A blue laser will not turn off a red.

Comment: @Philip yes, the entire beam dies. It does not stop at the beam splitter. It stops at the laser.

Comment: @philip did you reach the point where it shows that when the screen is dark the beam is going back to the laser source?

Comment: @ThePhoton  Thats why I said it is a comment. It points to an analogus ,  one of the beams putting off the lazing mechanicsm of the other, depending on the phases.. It makes the point that it is not just the light beams that are playing in the setup, but also the two lazing media.

Comment: @philip sorry, it is the wrong link watch this  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRi4dv9KgCg , there are a number of such mit videos. I will correct

Comment: @ThePhoton i had the wrong mit video

Comment: @annav Right, this makes more sense, but I'm still not completely clear about how it relates to the OP's question. The way I see it, nothing in the video has anything to do with the way the light is produced in the laser. When destructive interference occurs in the interferometer (in ''front'' of the beamsplitter), constructive interference occurs ''behind'' it because reflection adds another factor of $\pi/2$ to the phase, and vice versa. I don't believe it has anything to do with the medium that produces the light (except that it produces a coherent beam).

Comment: On the other hand, if your claim is that in the OP's setup, the reflected beam from one laser and the transmitted beam from the other cancel out on one side of the beamsplitter, but add up constructively on the other, I could sort of see it possible, except that that would mean that the phases on either side of the beamsplitter must have a difference of phase of $\pi/2$ between them, and I can't see how that would happen. The way I see it, they should both be the same. (Apologies for the long comments.)

Comment: @annav I posted a video to my question.

Comment: Correction to my comment above where I say it stops at the laser. It does Not stop at the laser it stops at the beam splitter. See my videos above for the details.

Comment: If it stops at the  beam splitter, what happens to consrvation of energy ? The reason that in the MIT video I talk of the lasing crystals is because of conservation of energy at the quantum mechanical level. It is like a resonating system  and  the screen is at a low point when everything goes black.

Comment: I saw the video. Maybe you should ask the MIT professor who put up the video. I think if the frequency is the same it does no matter that they are separate lasers . One needs coherent beams same frequency ( within widths). If the lasers are the same make/crystal ?

Comment: You might be interested in this question  https://www.researchgate.net/post/The_interference_between_two_different_lasers_at_the_same_wavelength . there are a lot of references in the answers that say yes, there is interference of indepedent coherent beams